# Ionic android build error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build, build.gradle

Ionic app shows build error when I am running a command "ionic cordova run android".

Error:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms.license'

Can anyone please help to resolve this?

Comment: please post what frameworks you have in your config.xml file or which libraries you are using.

Comment: I am using cordova firebase plugin. 
Project properties file

target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-firebase/app-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.gms:google-services:11.+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.+

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: @akhilaet its because of `com.google.gms:google-services:11.+` which means including all google-play-services modules. You should remove it and check which module you need to use that module instead of whole google-play-services.

Comment: Yes. I have removed 11.+ from com.google.gms:google-services and updated firebase version. Finally, the issue is resolved